# How to set properly Java bean class as field type in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans, ireport

I know this is a newbie question but I came across a sample project that uses java class as field type as oppose to using **"java.lang.String"**. I'm trying to implement the example on my project but I keep getting

`"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: profiling.Employee"`.

I also tested the connection. My question is that what is the proper way of implementing this in iReport?

[image]
[image]
I am using **iReportDesigner5.6.0**

Comment: Did you add *jar* file?

Comment: Yes. I even added classes folder .

Comment: do you have any other suggestions? I've been working on this for hours. I don't know what I missed here.

Answer (score 0):

The *jar* with Bean should be added via *"Tools -> Options"* menu. After opening *"Options"* dialog you can add *jar* with *"Add JAR"* button on *"Classpath"* tab. Maybe you should restart *iReport* after adding new *jar*.

[image: Adding jar to iReport]

After that you can use the bean at report, like at this sample:

Report's template (*jrxml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="bean_sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" >
    <field name="field1" class="ru.alex.samples.CustomBean"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The field's properties:

[image: Field's properties]

It is compiling well in *iReport* after this simple steps:

[image: Compiling results]

---

#### Notes

Don't forget to set fully qualified class name (with package name). At my sample it was: ***ru.alex.samples.CustomBean***